# ReferenceError: Theme is not defined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

This is an odd error that is happening with `@react-navigation/native` Version `^6.1.6`
`ReferenceError: Theme is not defined` 
I have tried to roll the version back to a more stable version but this makes no difference. Please can someone help me who has encountered this error?

```
export const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={SplashScreen}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: false,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignUpScreen" component={SignUpScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="FixturesScreen" component={FixturesScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ErrorScreen" component={ErrorScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ChangeName" component={ChangeName} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UserProfilesScreen" component={UserProfilesScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Then I am importing the `MainNavigator` in the app.js file with:

`import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MainNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code except your `initialRouteName` that should be `"Splash"` instead of the actual component

Comment: Yeah I added it to show that there is nothing wrong with the code but more with the NavigationContainer, and if anyone else had encountered this same error.